# Convert ul with onclick() into select with onchange()

Tags: javascript, list, select, onchange, tritium

I have a ul containing a series of tabs with onclick() attributes, and I want to convert it into a select node with options instead of list items. Right now each tab has its own onclick() attribute, but it looks like a select node only has one onchange() attribute. How do I tell the select to run the js indicated by the selected option on change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `onchange` event runs get the `.value` like you would for any time of form element and then run whatever javascript is appropriate.

```
document.getElementById('selectElement').onchange=function(e){
  var ele = event.target || event.srcElement;//This would be the select element
  var val=ele.value;
  if(val=='option1'){
    callFunction1();
  }
  else if(val=='option2'){
    callFunction2();
  }
  //Alternatively you could set up an object for all your functions and call it like this
  var actions={
    option1:function(){},
    option2:function(){}
  }
  actions[val]()
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not great with javascript and that's not really telling me anything  :\